# 22.04.1 LTS rpool devices present in Files, but not using ZFS

Tags: partitioning, mount, zfs

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on an old laptop PC.  I initially used the ZFS file system option during the installation, but after reading about ZFS vs. ext4fs for my use case (single small drive, low-powered PC), I decided to switch to ext4fs.  I reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch, wiping the disk and leaving the default ext4fs option selected.

Everything is working fine, except I have 2 "rpool" devices shown in Files: /dev/mmcblk1boot0 and /dev/mmcblk1boot1 (mmcblk1 is the only drive in the PC).  I cannot mount them (the error upon trying is "unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'"), and I can't get rid of them either.  `fdisk -l` shows only 2 partitions on mmcblk1: a small EFI partition, and a main ext4fs partition as expected.

Question: How can I get rid of these "rpool" devices so that they no longer show up in Files?  This is the only place where I can see them, and I have no idea where they're coming from since I'm not running ZFS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.  Hopefully this helps someone!
https://icesquare.com/wordpress/freebsdhow-to-remove-zfs-meta-data/

`zpool labelclear -f /dev/mmcblk1` did the trick.